# Restrict Edit/Delete SharePoint Permission on list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How to create a SharePoint permission that will only allow users to add items but no modify and delete access?

This will help me to secure all the data or information that the user input to SharePoint list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint default policies you can not restrict user. You have to create your own policy first. Follow below steps to create your own policy.

- Go to site settings -> site permissions.
- From ribbon click on permission levels.
- click on "Add a new permission level".
- Provide name and In list permission select "add permission" check box. click Create.

Now create group with this new permission policy and add appropriate user in it.

Go to your list -> list settings -> Permission for this list. Stop inheriting permission. Remove unwanted groups from there and add the new group you have created.

Now your users have only add permission in this list.